# Не забрасывать в файл данные, которые уже есть

Tags: 1с

Подскажите пожалуйста, 1с 8, УП, Тонкий клиент, серверная БД, есть обработка, которая выгружает всех сотрудников в файл .csv, есть функция, которая получает всех сотрудников, как мне ее сравнить с файлом .csv, что-бы не добавлять одинаковые значения?
Вот функция для получения работников:
Функция ПолучитьОстатки()

```
Запрос = Новый Запрос;

ТекстЗапроса = "ВЫБРАТЬ
               |    Сотрудники.Наименование КАК Наименование,
               |    Сотрудники.Код КАК Код,
               |    ТекущиеКадровыеДанныеСотрудников.ДатаПриема КАК ДатаПриема,
               |    ТекущиеКадровыеДанныеСотрудников.ДатаУвольнения КАК ДатаУвольнения
               |ИЗ
               |    Справочник.Сотрудники КАК Сотрудники
               |        ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ РегистрСведений.ТекущиеКадровыеДанныеСотрудников КАК ТекущиеКадровыеДанныеСотрудников
               |        ПО (ТекущиеКадровыеДанныеСотрудников.Сотрудник = Сотрудники.Ссылка)";

Запрос.Текст = ТекстЗапроса;

РезультатЗапроса = Запрос.Выполнить().Выбрать();

ТекстCSV = "";
Пока РезультатЗапроса.Следующий() Цикл
        ТекстCSV = ТекстCSV + РезультатЗапроса.Код + ", " + РезультатЗапроса.Наименование + ", " + РезультатЗапроса.ДатаПриема + ", " + РезультатЗапроса.ДатаУвольнения + Символы.ВК;       
КонецЦикла;
    
Возврат ТекстCSV;
```

Остальной код выполнения:

```
    ТекстCSV = ПолучитьОстатки();
    Текст = Новый ЗаписьТекста(ПутьКФайлу , КодировкаТекста.UTF8,,ложь);
    Текст.ЗаписатьСтроку(ТекстCSV);
    Текст.Закрыть();
```

Comment: Сравнивать по всем колонкам или какому-то одному критерию?

Comment: @Sagittarius, это я понимаю, мне бы пример кода хотя-бы, в 1с не силен

Comment: У меня был вопрос, не утверждение.

Comment: @Sagittarius Прошу прощения, по одной колонке сравнить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Сделать считывание *.csv файла, изучив примеры (например, [раз](https://infostart.ru/1c/articles/1498103/), [два](https://wiseadvice-it.ru/o-kompanii/blog/articles/zagruzka-i-vygruzka-iz-csv-v-1s/), [три](https://programmist1s.ru/zagruzka-iz-csv-v-1s/));
2. Добавить условие отбора в запрос (по требуемому полю), основываясь на считанных данных из файла, чтобы не получать те записи, которые уже в нём есть:

```
...
|    Справочник.Сотрудники КАК Сотрудники
|        ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ РегистрСведений.ТекущиеКадровыеДанныеСотрудников КАК ТекущиеКадровыеДанныеСотрудников
|        ПО (ТекущиеКадровыеДанныеСотрудников.Сотрудник = Сотрудники.Ссылка);
|
|ГДЕ
|    НЕ Сотрудники.Код В (&СписокВыгруженныхКодов)
```